# read twitter user timeline without authentication in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, twitter, tweetsharp

I have website had built by using ASP.NET c#, my website contains page called  my tweets page to display all my tweets from my account on twitter.

I seen many ways but all ways need authentication step , so it bad solution, I am searching about way do what I need, without need authentication step.

Summary:

I am looking to get posts from timeline as data or Rss to make customization for it in my website ,without need authentication step.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to display your tweets on you asp.net page.

You can do this by simply creating a widget and loading in on your page. this is a very simple process involving simple html and java script. Twitter will take care of the rest.

Below is the link

[embedded-timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines)

no authentication is required. 
One small correction, you can display a maximum of 20 tweets at once, after that user needs to click on load more to get the some more appended below.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really I am looking to get post from timeline as data or Rss to make customization for it in my website.